# Getting all properties of a collection by querying object in an array in Firestore, Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My cloud firestore looks somethng like this

```
Companies{
{
    name : Microsoft;
    rating : 4;
//this is the array of products
    products{
        [{software
        },
        {hardware
        }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I am using android studio and i would like to retrieve the name and rating of the company by querying one item in the products, either software or hardware. So far i am able to query using the name but now i want to query using the product.

This is what i have done and is not working

```
 Query query = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("products","oxygen");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CompaniesModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CompaniesModel>()
            .setQuery(query,CompaniesModel.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and tell us what is wrong with this code. Also, how is `collectionReference` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query query = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("products","software");